# Converting terminal printed output to CSV - rows to column

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have terminal output as shown below in the screenshot.
How should I dump data into CSV file and that too in separate column for each row?
I am using Ubuntu.

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

Comment: You can "dump" data into a CSV format file by using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module in the standard library. It doesn't matter what OS you're using. Typically this is done by putting the values comprising each row into a list and passing that to function in the library. If you can print the data to the terminal, doing this should be easy.